# Родительское и дочерние окна

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

у меня есть MVC система на PHP. За redirect отвечает отдельный контроллер, условно `RedirectController.php`

Суть вопроса - В данный момент контроллер контроллер в actionIndex передает `header` ссылку и открывает ее в новом окне.

Вопрос, как сделать так, что бы в родительском окне в это время открылась другая страница?

Comment: А покажите как ссылка открывается в новом окне? Это, наверное, джаваскриптом делается?